# Which is good method for step down 50Hz, 230V AC

Tags: ac, reactance

Which is low cost and safe for step down 50Hz 230V AC into 12V?

Transformer or reactance or Regulator IC ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGWrhp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are we talking 15V AC or DC you want this converted into?

Comment: After step down, I want convert to DC.

Comment: Is there something wrong with a 12V wall wart?  Phihong maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is low cost and safe for step down 50Hz 230V AC into 12V?

The key word in the question above is "safe" and this means using a method that inherently provides isolation. If you want to transfer some reasonable amount of power (rather than using an optical method that can transfer maybe 1 milli watt), you are forced down the road of using a transformer. This is how I read "safe" in this context.

In this context I assume that safe means isolation so that anyone touching the reduced-voltage output is not going to receive an electric shock.

Other safe methods involve providing sufficient insulation around everything that connects to the circuit - under these circumstances you don't need to use a transformer BUT be prepared, when building the thing to get your fingers scorched by electricity. A non-transformer method to reduce voltage can provide a fair amount of power (such as when using a switching buck regulator type of circuit) but it is still connected to live mains and can electrocute if not handled properly.

If using a transformer means more cost then this price is worth paying for reasons of safety and prevention of litigation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a transformer for the front end if you don't want to kill yourself.

Comment: But I think It will increase cost and size.

Comment: And leave less to pay for your coffin?

Comment: Not to mention the efficiency of transformers for stepping down compared to other methods... For efficiency and safety, a transformer is a small price to pay. If you want higher efficiency and a smaller size, look into a switching power supply configuration. Higher chopping frequencies reduce transformer size.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, one of the common ways of stepping down 230V-AC(50 Hz) is by using a step down (230V to 12V) transformer followed by an LM7812 IC to output 12 Volts DC. Between the transformer and the LM7812 IC, you can also use some filtering capacitors. If your application supports, you may just use a 9V (DC) battery avoiding the use of transformer.If i am wrong , feedback's would be appreciated.

And note that, you can use 9V battery, only if your working on some low power applications, or else the battery will drain out soon.